# jQuery - Append and Remove HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, removechild

In jQuery, how can I append a line of HTML to some HTML, as well as remove the line of HTML?

Here is the before code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the after code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="txtCvc" data-valmsg-replace="true">Test message.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am needing to add this line of code:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="txtCvc" data-valmsg-replace="true">Test message.</span>
```

Also, the reverse. How can I remove this line of code?

Here is the before code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="txtCvc" data-valmsg-replace="true">Test message.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the after code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="txtCvc">Cvc</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="txtCvc" name="Cvc" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am a beginner when it comes to jQuery. I am looking at the append and remove functions right now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And **in which situation** something should be modified?

Comment: No effort shown to answer yourself. You want to append something and remove something? Well have you tried looking at the [append function](http://api.jquery.com/append) and the [remove function](http://api.jquery.com/remove)? A quick [Google search](http://goo.gl/FVfKXS) is your friend here, not SO

Comment: @JamieBarker well, actually there are some "friends" in SO, who will write all code for you. They might say "we are helping", but in fact they encourage OPs not to try to do/learn/understand something yourself.

Comment: @Regent Yes, Rep farmers. ~_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) methods.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate if you use show() and hide() for an error message like

```
$('.field-validation-error').show();
```

for showing the message and

```
$('.field-validation-error').hide();
```

for hiding it, use if else for checking your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you know input field element that you want to show/hide validation messages for, you can use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to add message:

```
$field.after('<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="txtCvc" data-valmsg-replace="true">Test message.</span>');
```

and [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove it:

```
$field.next('.field-validation-error').remove();
```

So `$field` can be something like this:

```
var $field = $('#txtCvc');
```